# Android Volley - JsonArrayRequest with post parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using `Volley` to interact with an `API`. I need to send a post request with parameters to a service that returns a `JSONArray`.

I'm overriding the method `protected Map<String, String> getParams()` but it is not working:

```
JsonArrayRequest eventoReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Configuracion.URL_API_PROXIMOS_EVENTOS,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsea json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                Evento evento = new Evento();
                                evento.setCod_evento(obj.getInt("cod_evento"));
                                evento.setTitulo(obj.getString("titulo"));
                                evento.setDescripcion(obj.getString("descripcion"));
                                evento.setDireccion(obj.getString("direccion"));
                                evento.setImagen(obj.getString("imagen"));
                                evento.setPuntuacion((float) obj.getDouble("puntuacion"));

                                // Añade el evento al listado
                                listaEventos.add(evento);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // Actualiza el adaptador
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "eventos_proximos_usuario");
                params.put("cod_usuario", cod_usuario);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public int getMethod() {
                return Method.POST;
            }
        };

        // Añade la peticion a la cola
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(eventoReq);
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: the API don't receive POST parameters

Answer (score 8):

Try ...
StringRequest instead..

Reference:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox

**JsonObjectRequest extends JsonRequest**

**whereas StringRequest extends Request**

```
StringRequest eventoReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Configuracion.URL_API_PROXIMOS_EVENTOS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    hidePDialog();
try{
 JSONArray j= new JSONArray(response);

                    // Parsea json
                    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = j.getJSONObject(i);

                            Evento evento = new Evento();
                            evento.setCod_evento(obj.getInt("cod_evento"));
                            evento.setTitulo(obj.getString("titulo"));
                            evento.setDescripcion(obj.getString("descripcion"));
                            evento.setDireccion(obj.getString("direccion"));
                            evento.setImagen(obj.getString("imagen"));
                            evento.setPuntuacion((float) obj.getDouble("puntuacion"));

                            // Añade el evento al listado
                            listaEventos.add(evento);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
// Actualiza el adaptador
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "eventos_proximos_usuario");
            params.put("cod_usuario", cod_usuario);
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Añade la peticion a la cola
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(eventoReq);
```

Me just a beginner hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

try like this, 
I think you don't need to override the getMethod() method.

Pass the method type (i.e Method.POST) name with in the `JsonObjectRequest or JsonArrayRequest` like below.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "eventos_proximos_usuario");
                params.put("cod_usuario", cod_usuario);
                return params;
            }

        };

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same so I implemented a custom Request but I still can't get it to work... This is my attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971990/custom-jsonarray-volley-request-with-post-parameters As for your answer, it triggers the onErrorResponse...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I started to use Volley in my android project. I solved the problem by using StringRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest.
for example if you want to show a ListView with some server data...
Just use a simple StringRequest instead of JSONArrayRequest and implements the onResponse  Methode like this :

```
public void onResponse(String response){

            try{

            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

                try {

                       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                       // do something

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }       



            }

        }catch (JSONException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();


            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, YourUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (!response.equals(null)) {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", response);                    
            } else {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
        }
    }) {    

     //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
            return params;
        }

     //Pass Your Parameters here
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("User", UserName);
            params.put("Pass", PassWord);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.add(request);
```